# Add a translatabe text into panels

Tags: panels

i want to add a translatable text into panels.So I enabled the php filter and add this snippet :
Unfortunately it doesn't appear.What am I doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: This is the code I added: <?php  t('Limit text') ; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Drupal 6, ensure these edits are within the settings.php file, as this is where the translation will take effect.

If using Drupal 7, there are a few reasons why this may not work. Most usually, if the text you are translating contains anything that needs to be substituted (i.e. using %user:name etc.), then the text will be substituted before being passed to t(), and as such will not work! Also, the functionality of t() in Drupal 7 for attributes and variables is limited, so perhaps an additional module will be helpful.

For solutions using additional modules: Place the text in a basic page,  you can then use Entity translation to handle the languages and translation. @pedrosp also suggests that "to avoid SEO duplicated content issues, install Rabbit hole module and use the redirect to your panel page for those nodes."

Also, [i18n](http://drupal.org/node/1179034) has some solutions to tranlsate text within panels. It may take some playing around with however, to match the intended functionality of your site.

Finally, @Letharion has shared before some custom code to "force" a title to become translatable, perhaps playing with this to focus instead on where you would like your translatable content would also help:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_panels_pane_content_alter().
 */
function HOOK_panels_pane_content_alter($content, $pane, $args, $context) {
  if ($content->title) {
    $content->title = t($content->title);
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Hope this is of some assistance!

Comment: Thanks,you provided a lot of info,of course gave me a lot of help!